# How to call a class based generic API view from a custom function based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am having some problems and doubts about how to call my own API within my app.

So I have an API to which I can send data. What I want to do in a different view is calling this sent data so I can visualize it in a template.

First I was trying to call the API with the library requests inside of my view. Even though that works I am having problems with authentication. So I was thinking I could call my class based API view from my custom function based view.

But I don't know if that is possible, nor do I know if that is recommendable. I was also thinking that it might be better to do that with javascript? I don't know.... So my question is twofold:

a) What is the best practice to call an API view/get API data from my own app so that I can manipulate and visualize it

b) If this is good practice, how can I call my class based generic API view from my custom function based view?

Here is what I am trying so far:

```
my generic view

class BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    """Retrieve detail view API.

    Display all information on a single BuildingGroup object with a specific ID.

    """

    authentication_classes = [JSONWebTokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    serializer_class = BuildingGroupSerializer
    queryset = BuildingGroup.objects.all()
```

my function based view with which I try to call it:

```
def visualize_buildings(request, id):
    returned_view = BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView.as_view()
    return returned_view
```

```
my url

    path('data/<int:pk>/', BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView.as_view(),
         name="detail_buildings_api"),
```

When I call my class based view I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'`

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's certainly no point making an actual HTTP request to get your data, but I can't understand what you are doing in `visualize_buildings`. You seem to be just calling the API view and returning it; what's the point? Why don't you remove that function and just go to the BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView URL directly?

Comment: Well right now I am just trying to return it, you're right. But that doesn't work so no sense in writing more code. My idea was actually that when I manage to get the data from the api, I can then modify it and pass it modified to my template where I can then visualize it....

Comment: OK but what "doesn't work"? What happens? Note that `as_view()` returns a view, ie a *callable* which you then have to call: `return returned_view(request, pk)`.

Comment: Yes, my bad I should have added that (I updated my question). It tells me ```AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'```. But wait I'll try your suggestion

Comment: that throws a ```AssertionError: Expected view BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk"``` Even though my url conf should be fine since I am actually passing a pk

Comment: OK, you need a kwarg, so try `return returned_view(request, pk=id)`

Comment: works!! impressive.... thank you so much Daniel, a big help! Would you recommend doing this or is it better to make an API call from inside the view (using the library requests for instance) to get the data? I mean considering performance, maintainability etc..

Answer (score 1):

What you can do if you want is to call your CBV after its declaration inside its file for the sake of easiness when declaring its URL.

**views.py**

```py
class BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    .....


visualize_buildings = BuildingGroupRetrieveAPIView.as_view()
```

Then on your URLs, you use that name.

**urls.py**

```py
from . import views


path('data/<int:pk>/', views.visualize_buildings, name="detail_buildings_api"),
```

Comment: thank you very much Higor. But this is more for the sake of clarity I assume and is basically the same as calling it directly? I'll try it.

Comment: that throws me ```RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded``` It was enough to do ```return returned_view(request, pk=id)```. But thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's weird that it throws that error. But you're right, it's for clarity. I've added a part I forgot but it shouldn't throw that error.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way:

```
from django.url import reverse, resolve

def get_view_func(name_of_your_view):
    return resolve(reverse(name_of_your_view)).func

# if your are in a drf view:
get_view_func()(request._request)

# if you are in normal django view:
get_view_func()(request)
```